# Read specific columns with pandas or other python module

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file from this [webpage](http://www.exoplanet.eu/catalog/?f=%22radial%22+IN+detection+OR+%22astrometry%22+IN+detection+OR+%22transit%22+IN+detection).
I want to read some of the columns in the downloaded file (the csv version can be downloaded in the upper right corner).

Let's say I want 2 columns:

- 59 which in the header is `star_name`
- 60 which in the header is `ra`.

However, for some reason the authors of the webpage sometimes decide to move the columns around.

In the end I want something like this, keeping in mind that values can be missing.

```
data = #read data in a clever way
names = data['star_name']
ras = data['ra']
```

This will prevent my program to malfunction when the columns are changed again in the future, if they keep the name correct.

Until now I have tried various ways using the `csv` module and resently the `pandas` module. Both without any luck.

EDIT (added two lines + the header of my datafile. Sorry, but it's extremely long.)

```
# name, mass, mass_error_min, mass_error_max, radius, radius_error_min, radius_error_max, orbital_period, orbital_period_err_min, orbital_period_err_max, semi_major_axis, semi_major_axis_error_min, semi_major_axis_error_max, eccentricity, eccentricity_error_min, eccentricity_error_max, angular_distance, inclination, inclination_error_min, inclination_error_max, tzero_tr, tzero_tr_error_min, tzero_tr_error_max, tzero_tr_sec, tzero_tr_sec_error_min, tzero_tr_sec_error_max, lambda_angle, lambda_angle_error_min, lambda_angle_error_max, impact_parameter, impact_parameter_error_min, impact_parameter_error_max, tzero_vr, tzero_vr_error_min, tzero_vr_error_max, K, K_error_min, K_error_max, temp_calculated, temp_measured, hot_point_lon, albedo, albedo_error_min, albedo_error_max, log_g, publication_status, discovered, updated, omega, omega_error_min, omega_error_max, tperi, tperi_error_min, tperi_error_max, detection_type, mass_detection_type, radius_detection_type, alternate_names, molecules, star_name, ra, dec, mag_v, mag_i, mag_j, mag_h, mag_k, star_distance, star_metallicity, star_mass, star_radius, star_sp_type, star_age, star_teff, star_detected_disc, star_magnetic_field
11 Com b,19.4,1.5,1.5,,,,326.03,0.32,0.32,1.29,0.05,0.05,0.231,0.005,0.005,0.011664,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,2008,2011-12-23,94.8,1.5,1.5,2452899.6,1.6,1.6,Radial Velocity,,,,,11 Com,185.1791667,17.7927778,4.74,,,,,110.6,-0.35,2.7,19.0,G8 III,,4742.0,,
11 UMi b,10.5,2.47,2.47,,,,516.22,3.25,3.25,1.54,0.07,0.07,0.08,0.03,0.03,0.012887,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,2009,2009-08-13,117.63,21.06,21.06,2452861.05,2.06,2.06,Radial Velocity,,,,,11 UMi,229.275,71.8238889,5.02,,,,,119.5,0.04,1.8,24.08,K4III,1.56,4340.0,,
```

Comment: does it work if you do `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=['star_name','ra'])`?

Comment: No. It gives me a `ValueError: 'star_name' is not in list`. I tried something similar with keyword `names` instead of `usecols`, but that does not work neither (but runs without errors).

Comment: I don't see a either of those columns in that table, so maybe that's the problem. Post the first few lines of the data you're *actually* working with.

Comment: One problem appears to be that the columns names start with a single space, e.g. `" star_name"`.

Comment: @PaulH Yes, it's not visible on the table, but in the downloaded version it is. I added few lines above.
@ajcr I will try to play a little with the `skipinitialspace` argument in `pd.read_csv`. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I solved the problem. The answer will be under so others can see it as well :)

Answer (score 228, accepted):

An easy way to do this is using the `pandas` library like this.

```
import pandas as pd
fields = ['star_name', 'ra']

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
# See the keys
print df.keys()
# See content in 'star_name'
print df.star_name
```

The problem here was the `skipinitialspace` which remove the spaces in the header. So ' star_name' becomes 'star_name'

Comment: Thanks for `skipinitialspace`

Comment: The columns can also be specified numerically, e.g. `usecols=[0, 1]` will read only the first two columns.

Comment: @Daniel Thaagaard Andreasen, how would I write it if I also have to have 'utf-8' .. I have also to use skipinitialspace=True

Answer (score 44):

According to the latest pandas documentation you can read a csv file selecting only the columns which you want to read.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('some_data.csv', usecols = ['col1','col2'], low_memory = True)
```

Here we use `usecols` which reads only selected columns in a dataframe.

We are using `low_memory` so that we Internally process the file in chunks.

Comment: If you want the file to be parsed in chunks, you should leave `low_memory` to its default value of `True`. [See the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 7):

Above answers are for python2. So for python 3 users I am giving this answer. You can use the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
fields = ['star_name', 'ra']

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
# See the keys
print(df.keys())
# See content in 'star_name'
print(df.star_name)
```

Answer (score 5):

Got a solution to above problem in a different way where in although i would read entire csv file, but would tweek the display part to show only the content which is desired.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
print df[['star_name', 'ra']]
```

This one could help in some of the scenario's in learning basics and filtering data on the basis of columns in dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for sharing :) It is something along the lines I would do it now too.

Comment: learning the basics of it, trying to enter into data analytics, @DanielThaagaardAndreasen could u pls guide me the steps for moving ahead with pandas, any good source or tutorials.

Comment: Sure :) I think there are a lot to be found on youtube. I like this channel:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnVzApLJE2ljPZSeQylSEyg

Comment: Regarding the answer. In this case, pandas will load the whole dataset in memory first. It can be a problem if the file is huge.

Answer (score 3):

**I think you need to try this method.**

```
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

print(data_df['star_name'])

print(data_df['ra'])
```