# Python pandas - Function to get columns with their names

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file :

```
Test_Case   Value
Case_1      0.988532846
Case_2      0.829241525
Case_3      0.257209267
Case_4      0.871698313
Case_5      0.63913665
```

with pandas I have seen that we can get a column like this :

```
import pandas as pd
myExcelFile = "data.xlsx"
readExcelFile = pd.read_excel(myExcelFile, sheet_name=0, index=0)
testCaseColumn = readExceFile.Test_Case
```

result :

```
0 Case_1
1 Case_2
2 Case_3
3 Case_4
4 Case_5
```

The name of the column can be change, and I would like to create a function with two arguments to get the column I want :

```
def getColumn(readExceFile, columnName):
    return readExceFile.columnName
```

I would like to know how can I attribute the name of the column to my readExcelFile parameter ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: do you need the `usecols` parameter in read_excel? check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063231/read-specific-columns-with-pandas-or-other-python-module

Comment: It's generally better to access columns using `['label']`, not `.label`. Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AMC I have to review a code and rewrite it. In the code these lines are written several times. I want to create function to have a clear code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getattr`.

```
def getColumn(readExceFile, columnName):
    return getattr(readExceFile, columnName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `your_dataframe.column_name` works only with column names w/o space character and you've mentioned that column name can be changed, you can call for column name with `your_dataframe.loc[:,'column_name']` (see Alexander Céciles comment).

On the other hand, if your dataset has always the same structure (n-columns, first one with some categorical data, second one with values, etc.) then you can call it also directly with `your_dataframe.iloc[:,0]`, with 0 being your first column-of-interest in the set.

Finally if you really need to have a separate function (besides at least those two I've mentioned) which returns exactly the same output then you may use this:

```
def get_column(your_dataframe, column_name):
    return your_dataframe.loc[:,column_name]
```

... what is highly non-pythonic way of writing the code (see [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))

Comment: column name with spaces can be a problem, ```your_dataframe.iloc[:,0]``` can be solve this problem. Thanks for your help.